# Generating a runnable .jar file from a libgdx project in intelJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle, jar, libgdx

I basically just spent the whole day trying to get a runnable .jar file from my libgdx project working. In previous projects on a diffrent pc I used to simply navigate my way into the project root folder with cmd and used "gradlew desktop:dist" command. However right now I'm getting error message whenever I try this method.

[error](https://www.dropbox.com/s/w7gkha1rkf7ppq4/error.png?dl=0)

How do I know which folder gradle searches my "tools.jar" file from? I tried even copying it to a few places with no success. I'm using windows OS.

For IDE, I'm using intelJ idea with newest version. I tried to use the "build artifacts" method from IntelJ but what ends up happening with the generated file is that it instantly closes/crashes whenever opened. When running the generated file throught command prompt I get a huge host of errors too numerous to name let alone fix. It seems like it doesen't include the required structures / project folders properly when using artifacts build.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems, your environment variable points to the installed JRE(Java Runtime Environment), but has to the Java Development Kit (JDK), because `tools.jar` is one of the files used by the development tools. You can take a look at the [JDK and JRE File Structure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/jdkfiles.html) to figure out, where is `tools.jar` located.

So, you have to install JDK(if it was not installed) and make the `JAVA_HOME` environment variable to points to it.

Comment: Should I make a completely new environment variable called "JAVA_HOME" referencing to my JDK location? As I recall I never had such variable listed on any machine, I only had the JDK location in the "path" variable. This time however, I couldn't get the path working even though I removed all references to JRE and only left the JDK pathing to it.

Comment: @Nonetallt I suppose, it's a common solution to use `JAVA_HOME` environment variable, whisch is added to the `PATH` variable. Any way, you may try to add it. And check, whether you path pont to `JDK/bin` path, not the 'JDK/jre/bin'

Comment: For some reason I couldn't get anything to work within the "path" variable. However, when I created the "JAVA_HOME" variable and set it to jdk/bin directory I got a different error, stating that it was invalid. After that I got it working by simply changing the new variable to jdk root directory.

Comment: Yes, `JAVA_HOME` should points to the root of JDK, but PATH variable should contain `%JAVA_HOME%\bin`. Some applications servers and platforms depend on `JAVA_HOME`, but not on the classpath. Seems, Idea is one of them

Comment: It's still curious that I got it working with path method on another machine. I also suppose simply adding jdk root/bin to path shouldn't work since the tools.jar isn't located there.